# 4G WiFi dongle only works with certain power sources

Tags: usb, power-supply, mobile-hotspot

I have a USB 4G dongle that broadcasts a WiFi hotspot.

When plugged into a laptop, or a wall socket USB charger, it works and broadcasts a network.

When plugged into a car USB or cigarette lighter-USB it powers up but shows no network, in any car I try.

Is there some kind of grounding needed, does anyone know why it’d refuse to broadcast depending on the source of power?

---

**Edit**: to clarify working conditions

- **USB A Wall Charger (eg from a phone)**: good
- **Laptop USB A in house on charge**: good
- **Laptop USB A in car**: good
- **Laptop USB A in house on battery**: good
- **12V cigarette lighter in car**: fail
- **USB A in car**: fail

Tested in 2 different cars.

Comment: Too bad you don't have a [USB power meter](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hb2f1bdd2f72c4c0e9dae21aee7ccc44f9.jpg) that could measure the voltage and current from each power source, and provide possible quantitative differences. Otherwise you may have started a guessing game.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details on what make and model the dongle is. In general, those things need network management from the PC to work. Did you install drivers on the PC to get it to work? That is your answer: It needs more than just power to operate.

Comment: Are you stating that, **when plugged into a laptop in a car**, it works, but not when plugged into a 12V to USB adapter in that same car? Edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 my testing suggests no network management is needed, as per my original post it works correctly when solely plugged into a wall socket (using a generic usb A phone charger). I dont have the brand, as it’s a generic made in China /“eBay special”. It definitely works and tested it, just not when connected to any power source from a vehicle strangely

Comment: @ChrisShaw Wonder if the issue is wattage? You mention voltage, but that is fairly meaningless without wattage. Check what works and what doesn’t and compare the wattage; that should be a major clue.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely culprit is insufficient power. If the WiFi device lists its power input needs simply ensure your charger is capable of fulfilling all listed voltage and amperage requirements.

Keep in mind that it's extremely rare for USB ports in vehicles to have what would be considered contemporary USB power capability. Try another car adapter, preferably a unit that advertises Quick Charge 3.0 (QC3) to maximize the chances for success.

Why QC3? Although it's a Qualcomm charging standard that may not be required for your device, it is a bit of shorthand to find a charger that will support the maximum current supported by USB type A - which seemed to be working well for you on a household charger.